# Passing Viewbag value to javascript function

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC and trying from last 7 hours to pass value from viewBag to javascript function in MVC 5.
I have a string variable

```
ViewBag.c1 = "0.30"
```

and i passed it to view and stored it as a hidden element

```
@Html.Hidden("Superman", (string)ViewBag.c1)
```

and then i want to access the value of this hidden element in following js function

```
function getValue1() {
return parseFloat(document.getElementById("Superman"));
}
```

Comment: The hidden input is not necessary. You can just use `function getValue1() { return @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.c1)) }` and the controller code should be `ViewBag.c1 = 0.30F;` is you want a number

Answer (score 4):

```js
@Html.Hidden("Superman", (string)ViewBag.c1)


function getValue1() {
  return parseFloat($("#Superman").val());
}

//or

function getValue1() {
  return parseFloat(document.getElementById("Superman").value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var c1Value = "@Html.Raw(ViewBag.c1)";

function getValue1() {
  return parseFloat(document.getElementById(c1Value).value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply store view-bag value in JavaScript variable like below.

```
<script> var yourValue = '@ViewBag.c1' </script>
```